Doxygen + sphinx/breathe to document anonymous entities
I am using breathe and doxygen to generate documentation for a file which contains several anonymous enumerations. In my header I have this:
 /**
  * @briefy test enum.
  * 
  * @ingroup my_group  */
enum
{
    E_One 
    E_Two 
};

In my rst file for sphinx/breathe I have this:
.. doxygengroup:: my_group

The output page is fine, but the problem is that in output toctree I see this (image applied).

I would prefer to see just the enumerators as If they were constants. Or maybe something else, anything, but not the 'PhonyNameDueToError'... Is there any way to achieve this?

UPD: It turned out, that doxygen of latest versions does not assign any name to anonymous entities in xmls. Downgrading doxygen to 1.9.4 solved the issue.

Bad choice to downgrade, better would be to use e.g. the id of the enum memberdef
